# Unreported exception javax.script.ScriptException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Tags: java, events, action

This is a calculator App. When I try and compile it comes up with the following message `unreported exception javax.script.ScriptException; must be caught or declared to be thrown`

I have a feeling it is because the class is set as `ActionEvent`. I am a student so I am still learning :)

Any ideas? Thanks

\

Comment: where is your `ScriptEngineManager` code?

Comment: how are you handling exceptions in your code? You just provide the exception directly to your user, or you just wrap it in an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
// .. other imports
import javax.script.ScriptException;

// .. the rest of your code
if(source==buteq){
  try{
     ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
     ScriptEngine se = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");        
     Object result = se.eval(createEquasion);
     finalAnswer = result.toString();
     answer.setText(finalAnswer);
  catch(ScriptEngineManager e) {
     // handle exception
     System.err.println("Error evaluating the script: " + e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

In case you are dealing with any kind of exception outside of the method you can add a `throws` declaration on your methods signature:

```
// .. other imports
import javax.script.ScriptException;

// your method signature
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) throws ScriptException {

// ...

ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine se = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");        
Object result = se.eval(createEquasion);
finalAnswer = result.toString();
answer.setText(finalAnswer);

// ...
```

This should be it.

Answer (score 0):

In your this `actionPerformed` method the line `se.eval(createEquasion);` is throwing `ScriptException`. you have to handle this Excpetion.

Add below code to complie the class

```
Object result = null;
            try {
                result = se.eval(createEquasion);
            } catch (ScriptException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (result != null)
                finalAnswer = result.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

`ScriptEngine.html#eval` can throws two `Exception`

1. NullPointerException
2. ScriptException

`NullPointerException` is RuntimeException so compiler will not force you to handle this.But `ScriptException` is checked Exception, so compiler will force you to handle this `Exception` either insert the code block into try catch or throw it.

`try-catch` block

```
if(source==buteq){
       try{
            ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
            ScriptEngine se = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");        
            Object result = se.eval(createEquasion);
            finalAnswer = result.toString();
            answer.setText(finalAnswer);
       }catch(ScriptException se){
            ...
       }
}
```

`ScriptException` class declaration -

`public class ScriptException extends Exception{...}`

Please find more information -

- [Checked Exception ScriptException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptException.html)
- [ScriptEngine.html#eval(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngineManager.html)