# String containing math - Java

Tags: java, string, math

```
String x = "((3 + 5*1)/8)*14";
println(x);
```

How can I calculate the string?

Wanted output: `14`

output: `((3 + 5*1)/8)*14`

(I can only use Java!)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form
Might be help full to you

Comment: I get the error "Error:(107, 39) java: unreported exception javax.script.ScriptException; must be caught or declared to be thrown" when using that solution...

Comment: which java version you are using?

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/is-there-an-eval-function-in-java

Comment: you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432245/java-parse-a-mathematical-expression-given-as-a-string-and-return-a-number

Comment: @MarcoKoivisto when get a error search it first ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195253/unreported-exception-javax-script-scriptexception-must-be-caught-or-declared-to . if you read the answers correctly there is `throws Exception{` you skip it?? read exception handling too .

Comment: @MarcoKoivisto i can not test this right now,
my version is 1.6.

Comment: @MarcoKoivisto handle exception like this http://pastebin.com/Y5V3d6pn

Comment: Works, but I cant use it. I can only use Java, its for school.